# Not able to show fetched data from firebase into reactjs webapp

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import * as ReactBootStrap from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap'
import firebase from '../fire'
import '../App.css'
import Foot from './Foot'


class Appointment extends Component {

  state = {
    data: []
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.database().ref("appoinment").once("value").then(snapShot => {
      snapShot.forEach(item => {

        this.state.data.push({
          id: item.key,
          name: item.val().name,
          age: item.val().age,
          gender: item.val().gender,
          Description: item.val().Description,
          date: item.val().Appointdate
        });

      })
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='cardback'>
        <div>
          <br></br>
          {console.log(this.state)}

          <br></br>
          <h2 style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: '30px' }}>Today's Appointment</h2>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <Table striped bordered hover variant="dark" style={{ width: "1200px", margin: 'auto' }}>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td>id</td>
                <td>name</td>
                <td>age</td>
                <td>gender</td>
                <td>Description</td>
                <td>date</td>
                <td>Status</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

              **{
                this.state.data.map((item) =>
                  <tr>
                    <td>{item.id}</td>
                    <td>{item.name}</td>
                    <td>{item.age}</td>
                    <td>{item.gender}</td>
                    <td>{item.Description}</td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                )
              }**
                        </tbody>
          </Table>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>


        </div>
        <Foot></Foot>

      </div>

    )
  }
}
export default Appointment;
```

---

### This is above is code

I want to fetch data from the firebase to react-js application. I am able to get whole data at the console but not able to iterate it into table form. The is as below. In which I fetch data from firebase and pushed into an array data. So basically data is an array of objects. But I am not able to iterate i

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: How does the `console.log` output looks like?
I think you are just missing wrapping in parenthesis `()` around the `<tr>` returned by your `map` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mutating the state directly which will not cause any re-render. Don't do `this.state.data.push({id:item.key,`

**Use this.setState**

```js
componentDidMount() {
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref("appoinment")
    .once("value")
    .then((snapShot) => {
      let updatedData = [];
      snapShot.forEach((item) => {
        updatedData.push({
          id: item.key,
          name: item.val().name,
          age: item.val().age,
          gender: item.val().gender,
          Description: item.val().Description,
          date: item.val().Appointdate,
        });
      });
      this.setState({ data: updatedData });
    });
}
```